# How can I use a for loop to create a two dimensional array and assign linear values with an increment of 10?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to create a two dimensional array using a for loop and I want to assign values with an increment of 10. So far here is what I have and I am not getting the result I want...

```
package ~/TwoDimensionalArray;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 3;
        int columns = 3;

        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                array[i][j] = j * 10;
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is what I want my output to be:

```
0   30  60
10  40  70
20  50  80

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is what I keep getting:

```
0
10
20
0
10
20
0
10
20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should not print a new line after each number.
- You should only print a new line after each row is printed, that is, after each iteration of the outer loop.
- You should also print a tab character after each number so that the numbers don't stick together
- You should calculate the number at row i column j using the formula `j * 10 * rows + i * 10`. This gives you the correct number at each position.

```
int rows = 3;
int columns = 3;

int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        array[i][j] = j * 10 * rows + i * 10;
        System.out.print(array[i][j]); // "print" doesn't print a new line
        System.out.print("\t"); // print a tab!
    }
    System.out.println(); // print a new line here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what u want

```java
public class TempTest {
    static final int ROW = 3;
    static final int COLUMN = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[ROW][COLUMN];
        // assign values to array
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                array[i][j] = 10 * (i + 3 * j);
            }
        }
        // display array
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

and the result will be

```sh
0 30 60 
10 40 70 
20 50 80
```

I think u are not familiar with the difference between `print` and `println`, the latter one will add a new line. Try learn more about JAVA, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int rows = 3;
int columns = 3;

int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

for (int i = 0, v = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++, v += 10) {
        array[i][j] = v;
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```